# Installing tools for 3.12 kernel to run perf?

Tags: software-installation

I'm running on 3.12.0-5-generic on EC2.

I want to run `perf`, which is part of the package `linux-tools-3.12.0-5-generic`, which unfortunately no longer exists, it's been replaced by kernel version 3.13.

How can I get the tools for 3.12?

Alternatively, what's the easiest way for me to run `perf`?

Answer (score 0):

You could rebuild your current kernel to get the tools. Also you may be able to install the tools still using:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-tools-3.12
```